# Is there a shorthand for properties where I implement a custom method?

Tags: c#, class-variables, shorthand

```
public class ServerState
{
    public static Action stateChanged;
    private string currentMap;

    public string CurrentMap
    {
        get { return currentMap; }
        set
        {
            currentMap = value;
            stateChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class with dozens of variables that each need their own property so that I can invoke an action. In other words, I am going to repeat the above code dozens of times, and I feel that there should be a better way to do so.

Is there a shorthand for the above code?

Comment: the short answer is no. You could look at creating a code snippet for visual studio or rider if you use that

Comment: Do you really need them as properties? Otherwise you could store them in a private Dictionary<string,object> and use methods like ```T GetVariable<T>(string nameOfVariable)``` and a similar setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ServerState
    {
        public static Action stateChanged;

        private Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        private void Set(object value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            _values[propertyName] = value;
            stateChanged?.Invoke();
        }

        private T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var v)) return (T)v;
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(propertyName);
        }

        public string CurrentMap 
        { 
            get => Get<string>(); 
            set => Set(value); 
        }

        // You can make them in one line if you want
        public string CurrentMap2 { get => Get<string>(); set => Set(value); }
    }

    public class ServerState2
    {
        public static Action stateChanged;
        private string currentMap;

        private void Set<T>(ref T property, T value)
        {
            property = value;
            stateChanged?.Invoke();
        }

        public string CurrentMap
        {
            get => currentMap;
            set => Set(ref currentMap, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to use more than one event, or track if the value actually changed you can expand on this idea:

```cs
public class ServerState
{
    public static Action currentMapChanged;
    public static Action currentMap2Changed;
    private Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    private void Set(object value, Action onChange, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var previousValue = _values[propertyName];
        // Check if value has changed
        if (value != previousValue)
        {
            _values[propertyName] = value;
            onChange?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var v)) return (T)v;
        throw new KeyNotFoundException(propertyName);
    }

    public string CurrentMap 
    { 
        get => Get<string>(); 
        // Call `currentMapChanged` if value differs
        set => Set(value, currentMapChanged); 
    }

    // You can make them in one line if you want
    // Call `currentMap2Changed` if value differs
    public string CurrentMap2 { get => Get<string>(); set => Set(value, currentMap2Changed); }
}
```

Additionally, you should look into using the `event` keyword to stop other classes from firing this event. Watch out for static events too, they hold a reference to the listening delegate in a static context and require care to avoid memory leaks.